# Error message about username when using plotly r package offline

Tags: r, plotly, htmlwidgets

I'm trying to begin using plotly for R, but I'm having trouble with an error about username. When I try to execute the following code...

```
test=ggplot(diamonds,aes(x=diamonds$carat,y=diamonds$price))+geom_point()
test2=plotly(test)
plotly(test)
```

...I get the error message:

```
Storing 'username' as the environment variable 'plotly_username'
Error in Sys.setenv(plotly_username = username) : 
  wrong length for argument
```

I thought plotly's R package was available for use without a username via htmlwidgets. As far as I can tell, I'm using the latest version of plotly, ggplot, and htmlwidgets. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use `ggplotly()`

So,

`test <- ggplot(diamonds,aes(x = carat,y = price))+ geom_point()`

`ggplotly(test)`

Comment: Haha, and so ended the dumbest question I've ever asked on stackoverflow. Thanks for the quick help. That worked perfectly.

Comment: Also, you could have used plotly but you would have to do plot_ly().